# Does DRY infallibly lead you onto the path of OOP design pattern righteousness?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dry

Assume:  Your DRY senses are infallible.  Repeated behavior in your code reeks to you; it's nails upon the chalkboard.

**Question:  Does keeping DRY in the forefront of your mind guarantee that you will notice when you should be seeking a design pattern?**

It seems from what introductions to design patterns I've seen has been working around supposedly "needing" to repeat code.  Is this an OOP truth?

The possibly more easy question:  **Is there ever a time when dry will lead you away from OOP design patterns?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO that depends on the specific pattern. If you have the GoF patterns in mind: lot's of them are aimed at "separation of concerns". By factoring out a specific concern like object creation (Factory pattern) or object cloning (Prototype pattern) you will bring that part of your code dealing with this concern  to a central place, making the code more DRY.

Other GoF patterns like Flyweight or Proxy have a different nature, they are aimed at more efficiency or less complexity. Those patterns are mostly orthogonal to the DRY principle.

Comment: Thank you, this illustrates what seemed to be a difficult question to ask.  Stated in dead simple terms, DRY will lead one towards GoF patterns but only a subset of them.

Answer (score 4):

DRY and OOP are orthogonal. DRY should be practiced whether or not one is coding in a OO language. Keep in mind that DRY doesn't just apply to code.

Comment: I'm not seeing how DRY and OOP (specifically design patterns) are othogonal.  Maybe I should have tagged this as design patterns.  Maybe even another way to phrase this question is, "Can all design patterns be reduced to methods to sidestep having to right repeated code"

Comment: @MushinNoShin: As I explained, DRY is a principle that should be exercised whether or not one is coding in an OO language and further it doesn't just apply to code (it applies to database schema, documentation, build systems, etc.).

Comment: Right, but the whether or not clause implies that I can apply to to OOP coding.  So, it seems the original question still stands.  I'm asking about DRY in this particular context, under the umbrella of OO with an interest in how it interacts with design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

As others noticed, DRY and OOP are orthogonal concepts. The ultimate proof that DRY doesn't lead you away from OOP design patterns is that you can apply DRY when using languages which incorporate (some of the) OOP design patterns in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why thinking about DRY lead you away from OOP design patterns. Design patterns are there so that you do not repeat the mistakes other has done many times and come up with solutions for specific problem. So, no DRY does not lead you away from OOP design patterns.